# Not able to run machine vison camera and 3D Line scan cameras frame capture python script simultaneously

Tags: spinnaker, flir

I am using 3 machine vision USB FLIR Camera (Blackfly S BFS-U3-31S4C) and 4 3D GigE Line scan camera C6-2040-GigE.
When I am running frame capture script for machine vision camera, there are no errors coming.

But when I run both machine vision cameras and 3D Cameras, Sometimes Following error is coming in machine vision script and or it closes without error.

Server details:
OS : Ubuntu
Intel® Xeon(R) Gold 5220 CPU @ 2.20GHz × 72
Ram : 128 GB

Error :
`python3: /vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:786: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = GenTL::DataStream; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = GenTL::DataStream*]: Assertion` px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
`

Following is my machine vision camera code.

```
import os
import PySpin
import sys
import shutil
import time 
import numpy as np
import cv2
import datetime
import pymysql
import subprocess

savePath1 = "/home/pwil-server/Insightzz/code/FrameCapture/"
#For logging error
import logging
import traceback
#Logging module
camlogger = None

SIDE2_DEVICE = "21236088"
TOP_DEVICE = "21266010"
BOTTOM_DEVICE = "21266009"

fps = 15.0

topExp = 100.00
bottomExp = 100.00
side2Exp = 400.00



def acquire_images(cam_list):
    """
    This function acquires and saves 10 images from each device.

    :param cam_list: List of cameras
    :type cam_list: CameraList
    :return: True if successful, False otherwise.
    :rtype: bool
    """

    print('*** IMAGE ACQUISITION ***\n')
    try:
        result = True

        for i, cam in enumerate(cam_list):
            camSerialNumber = getSerialNumber(cam)
            if camSerialNumber == TOP_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == SIDE2_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == BOTTOM_DEVICE:
                # Set acquisition mode to continuous
                node_acquisition_mode = PySpin.CEnumerationPtr(cam.GetNodeMap().GetNode('AcquisitionMode'))
                if not PySpin.IsAvailable(node_acquisition_mode) or not PySpin.IsWritable(node_acquisition_mode):
                    print('Unable to set acquisition mode to continuous (node retrieval; camera %d). Aborting... \n' % i)
                    return False

                node_acquisition_mode_continuous = node_acquisition_mode.GetEntryByName('Continuous')
                if not PySpin.IsAvailable(node_acquisition_mode_continuous) or not PySpin.IsReadable(
                        node_acquisition_mode_continuous):
                    print('Unable to set acquisition mode to continuous (entry \'continuous\' retrieval %d). \
                    Aborting... \n' % i)
                    return False

                acquisition_mode_continuous = node_acquisition_mode_continuous.GetValue()
                node_acquisition_mode.SetIntValue(acquisition_mode_continuous)
                print('Camera %d acquisition mode set to continuous...' % i)

                # Begin acquiring images
                node_device_serial_number = PySpin.CStringPtr(cam.GetTLDeviceNodeMap().GetNode('DeviceSerialNumber'))
                device_serial_number = node_device_serial_number.GetValue()


                # for keeping rgb value constant
                ptrRgbTransformLightSource = PySpin.CEnumerationPtr(cam.GetNodeMap().GetNode("RgbTransformLightSource"))
                ptrRgbTransformationLightSourceWarm = ptrRgbTransformLightSource.GetEntryByName("CoolFluorescent4000K") #Daylight5000K #WarmFluorescent3000K #CoolFluorescent4000K
                ptrRgbTransformLightSource.SetIntValue(ptrRgbTransformationLightSourceWarm.GetValue())

                print(f"device_serial_number : {device_serial_number}")
                print(device_serial_number)
                if device_serial_number == SIDE2_DEVICE:
                    try:
                        cam.GainAuto.SetValue(PySpin.GainAuto_Off)    
                        cam.Gain.SetValue(27)
                    except Exception as e:
                        pass
                    if not configure_exposure(cam, side2Exp):
                        return False
                    try:
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRateAuto = "Off"
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRateEnable.SetValue(True)
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRate.SetValue(fps)
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRate_set = fps
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"AcquisitionFrameRate SIDE2 : {e}")                    
                        camlogger.critical(f"AcquisitionFrameRate SIDE2 : {e}")
                if device_serial_number == TOP_DEVICE:
                    try:
                        cam.GainAuto.SetValue(PySpin.GainAuto_Off)    
                        cam.Gain.SetValue(25)
                    except Exception as e:
                        pass
                    if not configure_exposure(cam, topExp):
                        return False
                    try:
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRateAuto = "Off"
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRateEnable.SetValue(True)
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRate.SetValue(fps)
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRate_set = fps
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"AcquisitionFrameRate top : {e}")                    
                        camlogger.critical(f"AcquisitionFrameRate top : {e}")
                if device_serial_number == BOTTOM_DEVICE:
                    try:
                        cam.GainAuto.SetValue(PySpin.GainAuto_Off)    
                        cam.Gain.SetValue(25)
                    except Exception as e:
                        pass
                    if not configure_exposure(cam, bottomExp): #3500
                        return False            
                    try:
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRateAuto = "Off"
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRateEnable.SetValue(True)
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRate.SetValue(fps)
                        cam.AcquisitionFrameRate_set = fps
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"AcquisitionFrameRate bottom : {e}")                    
                        camlogger.critical(f"AcquisitionFrameRate bottom : {e}")

                cam.BeginAcquisition()

                print('Camera %d started acquiring images...' % i)

                print()
        
        side2_once1 = True
        side2_once2 = True
        top_once1 = True
        top_once2 = True
        bottom_once1 = True
        bottom_once2 = True    
        cameras=[]    
        
        while True:
            date=datetime.datetime.now()
            try:
                t = int(time.time()*1000)
                for i, cam in enumerate(cam_list):
                    camSerialNumber = getSerialNumber(cam)
                    if camSerialNumber == TOP_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == SIDE2_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == BOTTOM_DEVICE:
                        # Retrieve device serial number for filename
                        node_device_serial_number = PySpin.CStringPtr(cam.GetTLDeviceNodeMap().GetNode('DeviceSerialNumber'))

                        if PySpin.IsAvailable(node_device_serial_number) and PySpin.IsReadable(node_device_serial_number):
                            device_serial_number = node_device_serial_number.GetValue()
                            # print('Camera %d serial number set to %s...' % (i, device_serial_number))

                        # Retrieve next received image and ensure image completion
                        image_result = cam.GetNextImage(1000)
                        if image_result.IsIncomplete():
                            print('Image incomplete with image status %d ... \n' % image_result.GetImageStatus())
                        else:
                            try:
                                # Print image information
                                width = image_result.GetWidth()
                                height = image_result.GetHeight()
                                #print('Camera %d grabbed image %d, width = %d, height = %d' % (i, n, width, height))
                                # Get image data as NumPy array
                                image_array = image_result.GetNDArray()

                                image_converted = cv2.cvtColor(image_array, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR)#COLOR_BayerBG2RGB
                                
                                if device_serial_number == SIDE2_DEVICE:
                                    try:
                                    
                                        filename = 'Side2/IMG_'+".jpg"
                                        cv2.imwrite(f"{savePath1}Side2/IMG_.jpg",image_converted)
                                        shutil.move(f"{savePath1}Side2/IMG_.jpg", f"{savePath1}Side2/TMP/IMG_.jpg")
                                        #updating cam health table
                                        side2_once1 = True
                                        if side2_once2 == True:
                                            update_cam_status("LEFT_POST","YES")
                                            camlogger.critical("LEFT_POST CAM is connected")
                                            print("LEFT_POST CAM is connected")
                                            side2_once2 = False
                                    except Exception as e:
                                        print(e)
                                        camlogger.critical("SIDE2_DEVICE 2 is not connected")
                                if device_serial_number == TOP_DEVICE:
                                    try:
                                        filename = 'Top/IMG_'+".jpg"
                                        cv2.imwrite(f"{savePath1}Top/IMG_.jpg",image_converted)
                                        shutil.move(f"{savePath1}Top/IMG_.jpg", f"{savePath1}Top/TMP/IMG_.jpg")
                                        #updating cam health table
                                        top_once1 = True
                                        if top_once2 == True:
                                            update_cam_status("TOP_POST","YES")
                                            camlogger.critical("TOP CAM is connected")
                                            print("TOP CAM is connected")
                                            top_once2 = False 
                                    except Exception as e:
                                        print(e)         
                                        camlogger.critical("TOP_DEVICE 2 is not connected")
                                if device_serial_number == BOTTOM_DEVICE:
                                    try:
                                        filename = 'Bottom/IMG_'+".jpg"
                                        cv2.imwrite(f"{savePath1}Bottom/IMG_.jpg",image_converted)
                                        shutil.move(f"{savePath1}Bottom/IMG_.jpg", f"{savePath1}Bottom/TMP/IMG_.jpg")
                                        #updating cam health table
                                        bottom_once1 = True
                                        if bottom_once2 == True:
                                            update_cam_status("BOTTOM_POST","YES")
                                            camlogger.critical("BOTTOM CAM is connected")
                                            print("BOTTOM CAM is connected")
                                            bottom_once2 = False  
                                    except Exception as e:
                                        print(e)
                                        camlogger.critical("BOTTOM_DEVICE  is not connected")
                            except Exception as e:
                                print(e)
                                # camlogger.critical("Image upload eror is not e")

                        # Release image
                        image_result.Release()
                time.sleep(0.05)
                print(f'time for one loop : {int(time.time()*1000) - t}')
                    
                    
            except PySpin.SpinnakerException as ex:
                if side2_once1:
                    side2_once2 = True
                    update_cam_status("LEFT_POST","NO")
                    camlogger.critical("LEFT_POST CAM is not connected")
                    camlogger.critical(ex)
                    side2_once2 = True
                if top_once1:
                    top_once2 = True
                    update_cam_status("TOP_POST","NO")
                    camlogger.critical("TOP CAM is not connected")
                    camlogger.critical(ex)
                    top_once2 = True    
                if bottom_once1:
                    bottom_once2 = True
                    update_cam_status("BOTTOM_POST","NO")
                    camlogger.critical("BOTTOM CAM is not connected")
                    camlogger.critical(ex)
                    bottom_once2 = True                
                print('Error: %s' % ex)
                camlogger.critical('Error: %s' % ex)
                result = False
   

    except PySpin.SpinnakerException as ex:
        #update_cam_status("LEFT_POST","NO")
        camlogger.critical("LEFT_POST CAM is not connected")
        print("LEFT_POST CAM is connected")
        #update_cam_status("TOP_POST","NO")
        camlogger.critical("TOP CAM is not connected")
        print("TOP CAM is connected")
        #update_cam_status("BOTTOM_POST","NO")
        camlogger.critical("BOTTOM CAM is not connected")
        print("BOTTOM CAM is connected")        

        camlogger.critical('Error: %s' % ex)
        print('Error: %s' % ex)
        camlogger.critical("while loop error | calling restartFrameCapturePath",ex)
        # subprocess.call(["sh", restartFrameCapturePath])
        
        result = False
    for cam in cam_list:
        camSerialNumber = getSerialNumber(cam)
        if camSerialNumber == TOP_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == SIDE2_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == BOTTOM_DEVICE:
            cam.EndAcquisition()
    return result

def configure_exposure(cam, exposure_value):
    print('*** CONFIGURING EXPOSURE ***\n')

    try:
        result = True

        if cam.ExposureAuto.GetAccessMode() != PySpin.RW:
            print('Unable to disable automatic exposure. Aborting...')
            return False

        cam.ExposureAuto.SetValue(PySpin.ExposureAuto_Off)
        print('Automatic exposure disabled...')

        if cam.ExposureTime.GetAccessMode() != PySpin.RW:
            print('Unable to set exposure time. Aborting...')
            return False

        # Ensure desired exposure time does not exceed the maximum
        exposure_time_to_set = exposure_value
        exposure_time_to_set = min(cam.ExposureTime.GetMax(), exposure_time_to_set)
        cam.ExposureTime.SetValue(exposure_time_to_set)
        print('Shutter time set to %s us...\n' % exposure_time_to_set)

    except PySpin.SpinnakerException as ex:
        camlogger.critical("configure_exposure  error | calling restartFrameCapturePath",ex)
        subprocess.call(["sh", restartFrameCapturePath])
        print('Error: %s' % ex)
        result = False
        camlogger.critical("configure_exposure  error",ex)

    return result

def print_device_info(nodemap, cam_num):
    """
    This function prints the device information of the camera from the transport
    layer; please see NodeMapInfo example for more in-depth comments on printing
    device information from the nodemap.

    :param nodemap: Transport layer device nodemap.
    :param cam_num: Camera number.
    :type nodemap: INodeMap
    :type cam_num: int
    :returns: True if successful, False otherwise.
    :rtype: bool
    """

    print('Printing device information for camera %d... \n' % cam_num)

    try:
        result = True
        node_device_information = PySpin.CCategoryPtr(nodemap.GetNode('DeviceInformation'))

        if PySpin.IsAvailable(node_device_information) and PySpin.IsReadable(node_device_information):
            features = node_device_information.GetFeatures()
            for feature in features:
                node_feature = PySpin.CValuePtr(feature)
                print('%s: %s' % (node_feature.GetName(),
                                  node_feature.ToString() if PySpin.IsReadable(node_feature) else 'Node not readable'))

        else:
            print('Device control information not available.')
        print()

    except PySpin.SpinnakerException as ex:
        print('Error: %s' % ex)
        camlogger.critical("print_device_info  error",ex)
        return False
       
    return result

def getSerialNumber(cam):
    try:
        device_serial_number = ''
        nodemap_tldevice = cam.GetTLDeviceNodeMap()
        node_device_serial_number = PySpin.CStringPtr(nodemap_tldevice.GetNode('DeviceSerialNumber'))
        if PySpin.IsAvailable(node_device_serial_number) and PySpin.IsReadable(node_device_serial_number):
            device_serial_number = node_device_serial_number.GetValue()
            # print('Device serial number retrieved as %s...' % device_serial_number)
        return device_serial_number   
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        camlogger.critical("getSerialNumber  error",e)

def run_multiple_cameras(cam_list):
    try:
        result = True

        print('*** DEVICE INFORMATION ***\n')

        device_list = []
        for i, cam in enumerate(cam_list):
            camSerialNumber = getSerialNumber(cam)
            print(camSerialNumber)
            if camSerialNumber == TOP_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == SIDE2_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == BOTTOM_DEVICE:
                # Retrieve TL device nodemap
                nodemap_tldevice = cam.GetTLDeviceNodeMap()
                #adding device number to the device list 
                device_list.append(getSerialNumber(cam))
                # Print device information
                result &= print_device_info(nodemap_tldevice, i)
            
        for device in device_list:
            if SIDE2_DEVICE in device_list:
                update_cam_status("LEFT_POST","YES")
                camlogger.critical("LEFT_POST CAM is connected")
                print("LEFT_POST CAM is connected")
            if TOP_DEVICE in device_list:
                update_cam_status("TOP_POST","YES")
                camlogger.critical("TOP CAM is connected")
                print("TOP CAM is connected")
            if BOTTOM_DEVICE in device_list:
                update_cam_status("BOTTOM_POST","YES")
                camlogger.critical("BOTTOM CAM is connected")
                print("BOTTOM CAM is connected")            
                
        # Initialize each camera
        #
        # *** NOTES ***
        # You may notice that the steps in this function have more loops with
        # less steps per loop; this contrasts the AcquireImages() function
        # which has less loops but more steps per loop. This is done for
        # demonstrative purposes as both work equally well.
        #
        # *** LATER ***
        # Each camera needs to be deinitialized once all images have been
        # acquired.
        for i, cam in enumerate(cam_list):
            camSerialNumber = getSerialNumber(cam)
            if camSerialNumber == TOP_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == SIDE2_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == BOTTOM_DEVICE:
                # Initialize camera
                cam.Init()

        # Acquire images on all cameras
        result &= acquire_images(cam_list)

        # Deinitialize each camera
        #
        # *** NOTES ***
        # Again, each camera must be deinitialized separately by first
        # selecting the camera and then deinitializing it.
        for cam in cam_list:
            camSerialNumber = getSerialNumber(cam)
            if camSerialNumber == TOP_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == SIDE2_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == BOTTOM_DEVICE:
                # Deinitialize camera
                cam.DeInit()

        # Release reference to camera
        # NOTE: Unlike the C++ examples, we cannot rely on pointer objects being automatically
        # cleaned up when going out of scope.
        # The usage of del is preferred to assigning the variable to None.
        del cam

    except PySpin.SpinnakerException as ex:
        print('Error: %s' % ex)
        result = False
        camlogger.critical("main  error",ex)
        camlogger.critical("main  error | calling restartFrameCapturePath",ex)
        # subprocess.call(["sh", restartFrameCapturePath])

    return result


def main():
    try:
        try:
            test_file = open('test.txt', 'w+')
        except IOError:
            print('Unable to write to current directory. Please check permissions.')
            input('Press Enter to exit...')
            return False

        test_file.close()
        os.remove(test_file.name)

        result = True

        system = PySpin.System.GetInstance()

        # Get current library version
        version = system.GetLibraryVersion()
        print('Library version: %d.%d.%d.%d' % (version.major, version.minor, version.type, version.build))

        # Retrieve list of cameras from the system
        cam_list = system.GetCameras()

        num_cameras = cam_list.GetSize()

        print('Number of cameras detected: %d' % num_cameras)

        # Finish if there are no cameras
        if num_cameras == 0:
            update_cam_status("LEFT_POST","NO")
            update_cam_status("TOP_POST","NO")
            update_cam_status("BOTTOM_POST","NO")        

            # Clear camera list before releasing system
            cam_list.Clear()

            # Release system instance
            system.ReleaseInstance()

            print('Not enough cameras!')
            input('Done! Press Enter to exit...')
            return False

        # Run example on all cameras
        print('Running example for all cameras...')

        result = run_multiple_cameras(cam_list)

        print('Example complete... \n')

        # Clear camera list before releasing system
        for cam in cam_list:
            camSerialNumber = getSerialNumber(cam)
            if camSerialNumber == TOP_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == SIDE2_DEVICE or camSerialNumber == BOTTOM_DEVICE:
                cam.Clear()
                # Deinitialize camera
                cam.DeInit()

        # Release system instance
        system.ReleaseInstance()

        input('Done! Press Enter to exit...')
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        camlogger.critical("main  error",e)
        # subprocess.call(["sh", restartFrameCapturePath])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if main():
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        sys.exit(1)
```

Following is my 3D Camera code

```
#for single instance
from tendo import singleton
me = singleton.SingleInstance()

import logging,time,os,traceback
from typing import Optional
import sys
import cv2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import subprocess
import datetime
import numpy as np
import shutil

from cx.device import Device
from cx.device_factory import DeviceFactory
import cx.cx_cam as cam
import cx.cx_base as base
device: Optional[Device] = None

topPath = "/home/pwil-server/Insightzz/code/Algorithm/3DCamera/frameCapture/top/"
topTMPPath = "/home/pwil-server/Insightzz/code/Algorithm/3DCamera/frameCapture/top/TMP/"

import pymysql
db_user = "root"
db_host = "localhost"
db_pass = "insightzz@123"
db_name = "PWIL_SURFACE_DEFECT_DB"

logging.basicConfig(filename="frameCapture3D_Top.log",filemode='a',format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
mv_logger=logging.getLogger("frameCapture3D_Top")
mv_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
mv_logger.debug("CODE STARTED")

processID = os.getpid()

def updateProcessId(processId):
    try:
        print("This process has the PID", processId)
        mv_logger.critical(f'This process has the PID {processId}')
        db_update = pymysql.connect(host=db_host,    # your host, usually localhost
                     user=db_user,         # your username
                     passwd=db_pass,  # your password
                     db=db_name)
        cur = db_update.cursor()
        query = f"UPDATE PROCESS_ID_TABLE set PROCESS_ID = {str(processId)} \
                where PROCESS_NAME = 'start3DFrameCapture_Top'"
        cur.execute(query)
        db_update.commit()
        cur.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception in updateProcessId: '+str(e))
        mv_logger.critical('Exception in updateProcessId: '+str(e))

def grabImage(device):
    try:
        # 4.1 Grab image buffer, wait for image with optional timeout
        dev_buffer = device.waitForBuffer(10000)
        if dev_buffer is None:
            logging.error("Failed to get buffer")
            exit(0)
        # 4.2 get image from buffer
        # the img object holds a reference to the data in the internal buffer, if you need the image data after cx_queueBuffer you need to copy it!
        img = dev_buffer.getImage()
        if img is None:
            logging.error("Failed get image from buffer")
            exit(0)
        # copy img.data
        img_data = np.copy(img.data)
        # 4.3 Queue back the buffer. From now on the img.data is not valid anymore and might be overwritten with new image data at any time!
        if dev_buffer.queueBuffer() is False:
            logging.error("Failed to queue back buffer")
            exit(0)
        return img_data
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception in grabImage: '+str(e))
        mv_logger.critical('Exception in grabImage: '+str(e))

def checkCameraConnection(deviceParam):
    try:
        print(f"Successfully connected to camera device {deviceParam.DeviceSerialNumber} {deviceParam.DeviceModel} - {deviceParam.DeviceIP}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error in checkCameraConnection {deviceParam.DeviceSerialNumber}: {e}')

def setCameraParam(deviceParam,device):
    try:
        mode=device.getParam("DeviceScanType")
        device.setParam("DeviceScanType","Linescan3D")
        device.setParam("ExposureTime",20.0)
        device.setParam("ComponentSelector","Range")#"Range"
        if device.allocAndQueueBuffer(64) is False:
            # Further error messages are logged by the Device class
            exit(0)
        # 3. Start acquisition.
        if device.startAcquisition() is False:
            exit(0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error in checkCameraConnection {deviceParam.DeviceSerialNumber}: {e}')

def main():
    try:
        updateProcessId(processID)
        devices = DeviceFactory.findDevices()
        if len(devices) < 1:
            print("No cameras found")
            exit(0)
        print(len(devices))
        # Connecting first device via factory returns a Device object
        for i,item in enumerate(devices):
            if item.DeviceSerialNumber == '21910315':
                deviceParamTop = devices[i]
                deviceTop = DeviceFactory.openDevice(item.DeviceUri)

        checkCameraConnection(deviceParamTop)

        setCameraParam(deviceParamTop,deviceTop)

        imageToStichTop = []

        START = 0
        if not os.path.exists(topTMPPath):
            os.makedirs(topTMPPath)

        print('done')

        while True:
            try:
                t1 = int(time.time())*1000
                img_data_top = grabImage(deviceTop)

                print(f'time for one grab : {int(time.time())*1000 - t1} ms')

                imageToStichTop.append(img_data_top)

                if len(imageToStichTop) == 15:
                    Stiched_image_top = cv2.vconcat(imageToStichTop)
                    fname=f'tmp.tif'
                    image_path_top = os.path.join(topPath, fname)
                    image_path_tmp_top = os.path.join(topTMPPath, fname)
                    cv2.imwrite(image_path_top,Stiched_image_top)
                    shutil.copy(image_path_top,image_path_tmp_top)
                    imageToStichTop = []

            except Exception as e:
                print('Exception in main while loop: '+str(e))
                mv_logger.critical('Exception in main while loop: '+str(e))

    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception in main : '+str(e))
        mv_logger.critical('Exception in main : '+str(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

1. I have tried running the machine vision code seperately and checked for errors. but the code runs smoothly but when 3d code run simultaneously then machine vison code stops.
2. Tried upgrading and updating softwares

Expectations :
The machine vision code and 3d camera code to run parallerly.